# Action done for the whole life and is over now - Past Simple or Present Perfect?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-simple

If there is a man who had a beard and still has a beard, we would say:

*He has worn a beard for his whole life.*

What if he had his beard **shaved off** yesterday? Shall we still use **Present Simple** while mentioning the fact of him wearing a beard for the entire life? Or shall we use **Past Simple** instead?

Which of these sentences is correct:

*1. He has worn a beard for his entire life, until recently — he had his beard shaved off.*

*2. He wore a beard for his entire life, until recently — he had his beard shaved off.*

Comment: Unless he had a beard when he was a baby or child, I would not use 'his whole life'.

Comment: Usually we say he had his beard _shaved off_ if you mean removed completely.

Comment: The ***for his entire life*** element doesn't really make any difference to the natural syntax, so the basic choice here is between Simple Past ***He wore a beard until now*** and Present/Past Perfect ***He has/had worn a beard until now***. Where they're all perfectly valid - but I can't see much point in using the more complex verb forms, so I'd normally use Simple Past myself in such contexts.

Comment: "He'd worn a beard all his adult life until he suddenly shaved it off yesterday."

Comment: His chin is freezing.

Comment: Thank you for your input, have corrected "cut" into "shaved".  @mdewey

Comment: @MichaelHarvey wouldn't you use "entire life" even in a casual setting?

Comment: @KateBunting thank you for the example, I was thinking about adding Past Perfect in the question first. What if we omit the "shaved" part, would Past Perfect still be perfectly valid then?

Comment: @FumbleFingers  is it better to use a simple form in a casual setting, or you'd use it in formal writing, too?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty :)

Comment: He had his beard shaved off is simple past tense.

Comment: As a rule, it's "better" to use the simplest "valid" verb form in ***every*** context. It's bad enough when native speakers use unnecessarily complex verb forms in the mistaken belief that it makes their text more "formal, correct, authoritative". Non-native speakers run a much higher risk of using those more complex forms ***incorrectly*** (not just ***unnecessarily***), so the safest approach is to always use the simplest version you think will be "acceptable".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree, more complex structures sometimes sound unnatural. In this particular case, is Past Perfect unnecessary or incorrect?

Comment: _Had worn_ is only valid if he stopped wearing one at some point, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Note @Lambie's comment that *He **had** his beard shaved off* is simple (passive) past tense . Also note that *He **has worn** a beard* is ***Present** Perfect*, not *Past Perfect*. But per my first comment, all three verb forms (Simple Present, Present Perfect, and Past Perfect) are "perfectly valid" in your context. And KISS (Keep It Simple, Stupid! :) is a good principle to follow here, as in most contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I used [BUZZER} in Spanish and got suspended. But I guess around here we are much more liberal with our KISS. [meant as joke for those who fear I am insulting anyone.]

Answer (score 1):

> He wore a beard for his whole (adult) life.

Past tense for past facts.

> He had worn a beard for his whole adult life

Past perfect is also possible, to set up the contrast with the action of shaving yesterday.

> He has shaved it off.

Present perfect for present state (resulting from past actions)

> He shaved it off yesterday.

Past tense for past actions.